Is there a True Implementation of Lock Free Ring Buffer with fixed size?
I am running into issue designing lock free ring buffer of fixed size.
We have 2 updates during insert/push.
First update is the update of the tail pointer.
Second update is the update of the actual data location.
Even if we get the first update correct , before we do the second update, other thread can potentially wrap around and overwrite the location.
How can I do both in lock-free manner?
The Tagged approach avoids the ABA problem but how to deal with the 2 updates problem.
bool push(const T& item) {
    TaggedHandle tail, next;
    
    do {
        tail = tail_.load();
        next = tail.next();
        
        if (next.index == head_.load().index) {
            return false; // Buffer is full
        }
    } while (!tail_.compare_exchange_strong(tail, next));
    
    buffer_[tail.index] = item; // This update can be corrupted if other threads wraps arounds and updates??
    return true;
}


What is that "true" lock free ring buffer? Such where locks haven't been replaced with occasional busy polling? Perhaps it has not been invented yet.

"How can I do both in a lock-free manner" is probably the key misunderstanding. You've designed and implemented a specific algorithm, and discovered that it's not lock-free. You can't  glue "lock-free" on top of any random algorithm.

@MSalters: It's lock-free all right, it just isn't correct.
